# Unable to Mock Static Method Using PowerMock with 'any()' Argument Matchers

Tags: java

I am currently facing an issue while using the PowerMock framework to mock static methods in my unit tests.

Here is the static method I am trying to mock:

```java
public static AssetNav calcMarginNav(NavContext navContext, Integer model, int moneyType) {
    // method body...
}
```

When I attempt to mock this static method using PowerMock's `when()` method with `any()` argument matchers, like this:

```java
PowerMockito.mockStatic(NavBuilder.class);
PowerMockito.when(NavBuilder.calcMarginNav(any(NavContext.class), anyInt(), anyInt())).thenReturn(mockAssetNav);
```

The mocking does not work; it always returns null during test execution. However, when I specify the exact argument values in the `when()` method:

```java
NavContext navContext = new NavContext();
PowerMockito.mockStatic(NavBuilder.class);
PowerMockito.when(NavBuilder.calcMarginNav(navContext, 2, 2)).thenReturn(mockAssetNav);
```

The mocking works as expected.

It appears that PowerMock requires precise argument matching in order to correctly mock the static method.

This poses a problem because, for my set of test cases, I cannot predict exact argument values ahead of time, hence the need to use `any()` matchers.

Does anyone know how can I mock the static method without providing the exact arguments? Are there alternatives or workarounds to this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `any` does not match `null`, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem with mocking a static method, there are a number of gotchas. I am using Junit 5, it is possible to have both Junit 5 and Junit 4 tests in the same project. (IntelliJ Idea asks what kind of test to create, you just select Junit 4 or Junit 5, and it works in either case.)

As I understand, that "You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing" message is shown whenever mockito fails to find something for whatever reason. The "one-fits-all" error message may be very irrelevant and very confusing.

1. Specify `mockito-inline` in *build.gradle*, preferably the latest version:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    testImplementation group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-inline', version: '5.2.0'
    ...
}
```

2. You have to use try-with-resources to create a mock for the class that defines a static method. The mock has to be "closed" after the test, and try-with-resources "closes" it. (See how `theMock` is used in the code below.)
3. If a static method is inherited, it may look like there is no difference whether you use the base class name or the derived class name. In fact, there *is* a difference: you must mock the class that *defines* the static method rather than the class that *inherits* it. (See `FooReaderBase` in the code below.)
4. Use `any(MyClass.class)` instead of just `any()`
5. Note how `readUrl()` is invoked in the code below. It is mocked explicitly, but invoked, well, somewhere in the called code. (See `ft` and `loadByNumber()`).
6. In the code below we use `verify()` to make sure that the network query is made only once (it *is* important that network queries do not repeat unnecessarily).
7. One may argue that the example code must be refactored, that `readUrl()` must be defined in an interface, and `FooReaderBase` must implement that interface, and (optionally) `FooReader` must own a link to `FooReaderBase` rather than inherit from it. We would have singleton beans instead layers of static methods. Which approach to modularity should be preferred? It depends. A small project may have an implied non-functional requirement to be small (it may even be a shebang script), you may have no time to refactor the existing code, etc.

We want to test the following code:

```
    class FooReaderBase {
        ...
        static String readUrl(URL url) { ... }
        // in tests, we must mock readUrl()
        // because we do not want our tests to send queries via network
    }

    class FooReader extends FooReaderBase {
        // inherits rather than defines readUrl()
        ...
        static MyDataStructure loadFoo(...) {
            URL url = ...;
            var jsonString = readUrl(url);
            ...
        }
    }

    class FooTraverser {
        void loadByNumber(int n) {
            ...
            FooReader.loadFoo(...);
            ...
        }
        // we want to test loadByNumber()
    }
```

And the test is:

```
class FooTraverserTest {
    static final String jsonReply = "{....}";

    @Test
    void loadByNumberTest() {
        var ft = new FooTraverser();
        try (
            MockedStatic<FooReaderBase> theMock =
                        Mockito.mockStatic(FooReaderBase.class)
        ) {
            theMock.when(
                       () -> FooReaderBase.readUrl(any(URL.class))
                   )
                   .thenReturn(jsonReply);

            ft.loadByNumber(100);

            assertEquals(...);
            theMock.verify(
                        () -> FooReaderBase.readUrl(any(URL.class)),
                        times(1)
            ); // URL must be read only once!

        }
    }
}
```